# MEAN stack click-to-deploy Google cloud platform

Tags: mean-stack, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a MEAN stack app on Google Cloud platform using their functionality "click-to-deploy". Once my VM is created, I can ssh to it, clone my git repository and run my server. My app is accessible at the given IP address on the right port. Everything works fine until I end my session which automatically stops my server. How can I make sure node will still be running afterwards ?

Comment: Well I found the command `nohup` as a quick work-around but I am not sure if that is the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do it would have been to use the command `forever start`